# How can I control growth on a steep hill?

Tags: landscaping, wildflowers

I have a steep hill on one side of my home (20' down x 100' across) that is a pain and unsafe to mow. The top of the hill flattens about 10' from my home and the bottom is an unfinished lot that isn't maintained. The problem is that anyone turning on my road can see the hill prominently so I'd rather it not go wild.

What can I do to keep it under control without having to mow or weed constantly?

I live in the upper midwest and the hill faces the east. Hard landscaping isn't an option given that the bottom of the hill butts up to the property and would be demolished once the neighbor lot is developed.

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but I have seen and used a technique to mow these sort of slopes safely: have the mower roped, and you walk along the top of the hill, starting with the mower at the top and letting the ropes out on each pass to mow further down the hill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/ground-cover-for-large-sloped-area) might help you.  The "Gro-Low" sumac is excellent for covering large areas with low maintenance.  However you are looking at a few years to establish. Other perennials are listed [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/fast-propagating-inexpensive-ground-cover-border?rq=1) but you need a lot of perennials to cover it.  Shrubs are a better option.

With such a large area that will be undergoing change when the next lot is developed is not cutting the grass at all an option?  What part of the world are you located in?

Comment: I'm located in Minnesota, US. The Gro-Low looks to be a great option given the characteristics. While mowing is possible, this solution is more practical. The slope itself isn't expected to undergo much change. More the base of the slope, so this solution checks all of the boxes for what I need. Thanks!